# How to embed jasper reports in a vaadin 14 layout(Horizontal or Vertical)?

Tags: jasper-reports, vaadin14, dynamic-jasper

Trying to embed jasper reports in vaadin 14 layout. We are using vaadin 14 and trying to display jasper reports in a dashboard. We have tried using JRDataSource but its not working.
Some functionalities are not used in vaadin 14.

```
jasperReportIframe = new IFrame(url);
jasperReportIframe.getElement().setAttribute("sandbox","allowscripts");
jasperReportIframe.setSizeFull();
add(jasperReportIframe);//adding in a vertical layout
```

[image: Snap shows no report or its data]

Comment: Please share some code, what did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: plz check the code

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: If you change the URL to point to some other content, does that show? If you open the URL directly with your browser, does it work then?

Comment: No there are no errors on the console.

Comment: Yes if we change the URL to display some other content it is perfectly displayed.  Yes if we open the url on other browser, it works fine.